# Insert string in another string from chosen character till chosen character php

Tags: php

I have a scenario where I need to append `&wmode=transparent` after each iframe's src attribute.

I need to replace this code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/UPk1B1bxUPg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

to this (notice the end of youtube url):

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/UPk1B1bxUPg/?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a DOM parser to accomplish this:

```
$str = <<<HTML
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/UPk1B1bxUPg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('iframe') as $iframe) {
    $src = $iframe->getAttribute('src');
    $src .= '?wmode=transparent'; // use a regex for better results
    $iframe->setAttribute('src', $src);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: This also seems very nice code. I will definitely use it in future.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for your input. I have found a solution myself with some string replace functions.

```
<?php
$videoEmbedCode = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/UPk1B1bxUPg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
$appendString = '/?wmode=transparent';

/* Youtube video sticky menu overlap fix */
$searchStartLen = strpos($videoEmbedCode, 'youtube');
$searchEndLen = strpos($videoEmbedCode, '"', $searchStartLen);
$newVideoEmbedCode = substr_replace($videoEmbedCode, $appendString, $searchEndLen, 0);

print $newVideoEmbedCode;
?>
```

That did it!

Answer (score -1):

you can use a dom parser to get the job done easily. I'm going to use the native php dom parser : http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

so the php code looks something like

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($your_html);

foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('iframe') as $iframe)
{
$iframe->setAttribute("src",$iframe->getAttribute('src').'?wmode=transparent');
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: This is also a nice approach. I have found another solution myself and added a comment below. Thanks.

Comment: you're welcome. i highly recommend you to use a parser when you work with html.